# MapPath strange error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
string path = "~/Others/Muzica/Demo/"+interpret+"_"+album+"/";
CMSUtils.CreateFolder(MapPath(path));
```

where CreateFolder method is like:

```
 public static void CreateFolder(string path)
{
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
}
```

So i create that folder if it does not exists...
All works great locally BUT i do not understand why, if i put it on the server it gives:

> Failed to map the path '/gramma_prod/Others/Muzica/Demo/Vitamina C_De n-ai fi fost Tu /'.

at CMSUtils.CreateFolder(MapPath(path));

I have checked if: /gramma_prod/Others/Muzica/Demo/ exists on the server and of course it exists...

Does anybody see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..The problem was that 'interpret' value had a space at the end

> Failed to map the path
>   '/gramma_prod/Others/Muzica/Demo/Vitamina
>   C_De n-ai fi fost Tu /

Another reason to use trim() properly...